# Do we have a new favicon?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

One thing I've noticed about the design is that the site icon is still the "sketchy" looking GD.  Is this just a caching issue on my end, or do we not have a new one yet?

Edit: the main site seems to have one now, but meta is still left out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm seeing the new favicons.

You can try to load these two .ico files in the browser directly, and do a hard refresh:

http://sstatic.net/gamedevmeta/img/favicon.ico

http://sstatic.net/gamedev/img/favicon.ico

Otherwise I think browsers load the new favicons, eventually.

Comment: I shift-refreshed and they're showing up now.

Answer (score 0):

favicons are cached really heavily by browsers, so it may take a while for it to show up.